# Extracting text between html tags with multiple classes with DOM and XPATH

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I am trying to extract text between 1 HTML tags but fail to do this:

HTML - Text to be extracted (http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com)

```
<span class="font-4 box1-r">3,757,209</span>
```

PHP

```
$data = frontend::file_get_contents_curl('http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/'.$domain); // custom function that return the HTML string
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(htmlentities($data));
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$backlinks = $xpath->query('//span[@class="font-4 box1-r"]/text()');
var_dump($backlinks); // returns null
```

Comment: Check what you actually get in `$data`. Some elements my not exists in the initial HTML (generated dynamically by JS)

Comment: @har07 Checked *font-4 box1-r*  view-source:http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com and it's there alright.

Comment: Seems you don't understand what I meant. Another way to put this might be: try to open that link in your browser with JS disabled, and see if the target element is there (I haven't checked myself)

Comment: @har07 Yes, did this also, and same thing it's appearing the source code. Is not dinamically generated by javascript.

Comment: Yep, seems you're right. I can find the element using the exact same XPath (tested using HtmlAgilityPack, HTML parser for .NET). Try to save your `DOMDocument` to file and see if the HTML is different, somehow?

Comment: Your XPath looks correct (tested with lxml in Python). Could it be that DOMXpath does not return text nodes but only elements? (I don't know PHP and DOMXpath)

Comment: @paultrmbrth seems like that isn't the case (https://eval.in/567895)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is due to `htmlentities()` escaping all tag delimiters (`<` and `>`), so you end up loading a long string with no elements and attributes to `DOMDocument()` :

```
$data = <<<HTML
<div><span class="font-4 box1-r">3,757,209</span></div>
HTML;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(htmlentities($data));
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo (problem)`](https://eval.in/567967)</kbd>**
**<kbd>[`eval.in demo (solution)`](https://eval.in/567970)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>&lt;div&gt;&lt;span class="font-4 box1-r"&gt;3,757,209&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</p></body></html>
```

Comment: actually htmlentities converts &lt; to < in my case. It does the opposite, checked with var dump on *htmlentities($data)*

Comment: I don't have PHP locally to test. Is it possible that your browser actually do that? (var_dump spit out `&lt`, then your browser displayed it as `<`, care to check view source?) Or ultimately, as I've suggested before, have you tried to see the output of `$dom->saveXML();`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simplehtmldom library for this purpose (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). And implement the code as:

```
require_once 'simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com');
echo $html->find('span.box1-r', 0)->plaintext;
```

Comment: It is a solution but wanted with native DOM and Xpath.